# how to fix debug error with /filter delete visible rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to filter out rows with blanks in first column then delete the visible rows. But get a debug error when code runs.

#### 1:

```
Apply Filter
Worksheets("RDI Capacity Report").Range("A1:I3000").AutoFilter Field:=1, 
Criteria1:=""
```

#### 2:

```
Delete Rows
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("RDI Capacity Report").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

#### 3:

```
Clear Filter
On Error Resume Next
SourceWkSt.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0
```

I expect the code to delete all rows that have blanks in the first column.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.  Syntax error on my part I forgot to include the range on the delete stmt.
'2. Delete Rows
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'SourceWkSt.Range("A2:I3000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Worksheets("RDI Capacity Report").Range("A2:I3000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True